How to display Rive animations on a Flutter web app after deployment?
I'm working on a Flutter web application that incorporates Rive animations. While the animations display correctly on my local development environment (localhost), they fail to render when the app is deployed to a live server (Host-Gator in this case).
When running the app locally, the Rive animation is visible. However, after deploying the app to the server, the animation is missing.
I've ensured that the necessary files are present on the server's cPanel, and I've verified the Rive file itself.
I've tried various approaches, such as verifying file paths and ensuring the Rive asset is correctly included in the app, but the issue persists.
Here's the code snippet that includes the Rive animation:

import 'package:rive/rive.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: const RiveAnimation.asset(
            'assets/animations/my_animation.riv',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

In this example, I'm using the RiveAnimation.asset widget from the rive package to load and display the animation located at assets/animations/my_animation.riv.
I'm unable to provide a minimal reproducible example, as I'm not sure which part of my code is causing the issue. However, I'm confident that the problem lies in the deployment process or server configuration, as the animations work correctly on my local machine.
Can someone please help me understand why the Rive animations are not displaying on the hosted version of my Flutter web app and provide a solution to resolve this issue?

Is there any kind of console output error?

No, this error is when I deployed the flutter website to the server

What about the Network, is there any kind of network error? This problem generally arises because the file extension/mime-type is not allowed to be fetched by the client.
